# RVM does not download Ruby

Tags: ruby, rvm

I tried installing Ruby 1.9.3 through RVM while I was in a public Wifi that didn't allow FTP. This broke the download but since then

> rvm install 1.9.3

skips "fetching" and therefore I can't install 1.9.3.

I tried uninstall and remove with RVM but it's the same.

Comment: The same happened to me when my internet connection was interrupted while downloading, and phinze's solution to delete ~/.rvm/archives/<the ruby download> worked for me as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

rvm stores the files it downloads to `~/.rvm/archives` so if you clear out the partially downloaded `ruby-1.9.3-p0.tar.bz2` file from there it should try to fetch it again.

Answer (score 2):

`rvm reinstall [ruby]` will remove existing sources and reinstall a ruby from scratch

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing a system-wide (root) install, you should also look in:

```
/usr/local/rvm/archives
```

You can either remove the version thats there, or pre-populate it if you are trying to automate stuff and don't want to have to keep waiting on ruby to download.

~tommy